# Sort string array in java with 3rd element

Tags: java, string, sorting

I have 3 strings . Each string has a time in the string . for example, 
1) "1 09:53 AM 5"
2) "2 06:25 PM 7"
3) "3 10:21 AM "

I want these strings sorted according to the time. How can it be done in JAVA?

Comment: The question as it is written is not quite clear for me: are you asking how to sort items in a collection/array using custom comparison logic or how to extract some data (time in this case) from strings?

Comment: i want to get those strings sorted in such a way that the time which is mentioned in those strings will be in ascending order.

Comment: what does 1 represent inside `"1 09:53 AM 5"`

Comment: its a part of the string

Answer (score 2):

1st- Parse each line and do this: (Don't forget to remove the first number with StringTokenizer)

```
String str = "10:20 AM";
SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date data = formatador.parse(str);
Time time = new Time(data.getTime());
```

2nd - Save each Time object on the array list declared like this:

```
ArrayList<Time> list;
```

3rd - Sort the array

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: You should be recommending the new `java.time` API, it's much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<String> unsorted = Arrays.asList(
            "1 09:53 AM 5",
            "2 06:25 PM 7",
            "3 10:21 AM "
    );
    List<String> sorted = unsorted.stream()
            .sorted(comparing(this::stringToTime))
            .collect(toList());
    sorted.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This requires the method `stringToTime` with a couple of supporting constants as follows:

```
// Used to parse the time string to a LocalTime
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("hh:mm a")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

// Regex pattern that picks out the time string
private final static Pattern TIME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d:\\d\\d [AP]M");

private LocalTime stringToTime(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = TIME_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    matcher.find(); // Find time pattern in string
    return LocalTime.from(TIME_FORMATTER.parse(matcher.group())); // Convert time string to LocalTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "out of box" solution in Java. If you need to sort a collection of objects in a custom way, you should use `Collections.sort(collection, myComparator)` method and pass it the `collection` to sort and own `java.util.Comparator` interface implementation.

In your case, the `Comparator` implementation seems to be quite complicated, since you need to parse each string and recognize the date at first. So the main problem here is **how to recognize time in a string**. If you have determined time format, consider regular expressions to extract time from strings.

First of all, you need to implement your own time recognition logic. Then you can write a parser based on this recognition logic, that would return you a wrapper object containing original string and parsed date (you can use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.LocalDateTime` in case of Java 8). Then implement the `Comparator` that takes 2 instances of the wrapper object and compares their dates. Both `java.util.Date` and `java.util.LocalDateTime` classes implement `Comparable` interface and have default comparison logic, that uses **ascending** date comparison.